# How to stop sensor in slider phone in android?

Tags: android, slider, android-manifest, sensors

I developed an application in which I don't want sensor.

For that I use,

**android:screenOrientation="nosensor"** in manifest file.

But, In sliding devices when I open slider It doesn't work. So please give me some solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the android:configChanges attribute. By calling android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" you can handle keyboard changes yourself (through the onConfigurationChanged method).

Answer (score 0):

Add the configChanges and catch them using    `onConfigurationChanged`

```
<activity
    android:name=".ABC"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    >
    </activity>
```

configuration change function overridden:

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

Add all three and check it. screenSize is added from API13 and is required to catch the slider    orientation change.